# How to load large amount of database data into Java memory

Tags: java, hibernate, amazon-redshift

I need to fetch few columns from a database which has 100,000 number of rows. At the moment I'm executing a native query with `SELECT` and then loop through the results with `while (results.next())`. This operation takes quite some time. I'm using redshift database, is there a **faster** way to get the data into memory. They have unload function which moves data to S3. But i like to move that data through jdbc. The data can either be in JSON format or CSV format.

Comment: Can't you load set of data, process and then load another set of data.?

Comment: Are you loading the entire database into memory? Is that necessary? Why not lazily load and then inflate anything you do need?

Comment: i need to load the whole set into the memory. But im thinking of a faster way than using select. Worst case i will dump data though unload and copy the file from S3

Comment: You can load data first time and add it to data structure and next time you can load that data from your data structure. This might helps